# Array solo imprime ultimo registro

Tags: php, array, mysqli, while

Tengo la siguiente estructura.

global.php

```
<?php 
define("DB_HOST","localhost");
define("DB_NAME", "prueba");
define("DB_USERNAME", "root");
define("DB_PASSWORD", "");
define("DB_ENCODE","utf8");
?>
```

conexion.php

```
<?php 
require_once "global.php";
$conexion = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
mysqli_query( $conexion, 'SET NAMES "'.DB_ENCODE.'"');
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    printf("Falló conexión a la base de datos: %s\n",mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
if (!function_exists('ejecutarConsulta'))
{
    function ejecutarConsulta($sql)
    {
        global $conexion;
        $query = $conexion->query($sql);
        return $query;
    }
}
?>
```

subcategoria.php

```
<?php 
require "Conexion.php";
Class Subcategoria
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }
    public function seleccionar($idcategoria)
    {
        $sql = "select s.nombre FROM subcategoria s INNER JOIN categoria c on s.idcategoria=c.id WHERE s.idcategoria='$idcategoria'";
    return ejecutarConsulta($sql);  
    }
}
?>
```

prueba.php

```
<?php 
header("Content-Type: application/json");
    require_once "Subcategoria.php";
    $subcategoria = new Subcategoria();
    $rspta = $subcategoria->seleccionar($_GET["id"]);
    while($reg = $rspta->fetch_object()){
    $datos = array(
        'Detalles' => array(
            array(
            'nombre'=>$reg->nombre,
        ),
    ),
    );
}
echo json_encode($datos);
?>
```

El problema que me surge es que el array solo me imprime el ultimo registro de la consulta:

```
{"Detalles":[{"nombre":"aceite"}]} // este el resultado
//lo he hecho con foreach, for y es el mismo resultado.
```

el resultado deberia ser

```
{"Detalles":[{"nombre":"aceite"}],[{"nombre":"filtros"}],[{"nombre":"bujias"}]}
```

Comment: En prueba.php dentro del while, estas inicializando la variable $datos como un array siempre, deberias declararla fuera del while, y dentro ir concatenando los resultados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error parece simple, usted solo hace la asignación a su `array`  **=** en el archivo `prueba.php`. debería agregar un nuevo elemento por cada iteración. En el `while` cambie el `$datos = ...` por  `$datos[] = ...`

```
while($reg = $rspta->fetch_object()){
  //agrega elementos
  $datos[] = array(
      'Detalles' => array(
          array(
          'nombre'=>$reg->nombre,
      ),
  ),
);
```

Si desea tener una sola clave y luego ir añadiendo valores a este, podría hacerlo declarando el array antes y luego ir añadiendo como el anterior ejemplo.

```
//declarar el array fuera con la clave detalles
$array = array(['detalles'=>'']);

while($reg = $rspta->fetch_object()){
    $datos['detalles'][] = array(
      'nombre'=>$reg->nombre);
}
```

Comment: En realidad lo que quiere es que 'Detalles' dentro de $datos sea un array, el fallo es el que comentas pero el código no le valdría.

Comment: Estimado Dev.Joel, Un genio, funciono, muchisimas gracias, definitivamente es lo que buscaba, ya lo probe y funciono.

Comment: @VictorCompany según el formato creo que tienes razón, igual modifiqué mi respuesta para los dos casos. Gracias por el detalle

Comment: @VictorCompany gracias por su cooperacion igualmente,